# Basement Bathtub Backup

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I have 2 family house where 1st floor drainage system working fantastic. Now, 2nd floor bathtub and kitchen sink is connected to my basement bathtub drain. My basement bathtub backs up sometimes and after a while the water goes away. Sometime I see some bubbles in basement bathtub when someone take shower in second floor. I ran 50ft drain snake through my basement bathtub and nothing is stuck. 
I’m guessing it’s some kind of venting problem. 
Anyone know how to fix this issue without calling a plumber and paying lot of money?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a venting problem.

If your basement bathtub is backing up, I assume it is the lowest point in your plumbing drainage piping.  This typically means that the sewer service line to the city is clogged or restricted.

What snake did you use?   How far from your property to the city sewer main?   50' doesn't sound like enough.  How old is the house / sewer line, do you trees on your property?  You might also want to rent the scope to see the problem.

Rent the 100' sewer snake from homedepot and run that from your house out to the sewer main.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’m confused with the problem because one of the plumber said that if I have problem in the sewer I’ll have water coming out of the bathtub when I flash the toilet. In my case the toilet got no problem. Also the first floor water drainage has no problem with sewer or clog issue. Moreover the basement bathtub clogging issue happens sometimes only(not always). So if it clogs sometimes then the water stays for about hour or so and then goes away automatically and quickly. And then my bathtub drains the water very fast for couple of days.

Comment: If the blockage is far down and only a partial blockage you'd need to have enough water pushed into the service line to fill it and then backup to the bathtub.  A toilet flush is not enough.  First floor shouldn't have a problem, only the lowest point will have a problem.  Bathtub issue happening sometimes is consistent with a partial blockage far into the service line.  Again going away quickly if you have a surge of water that fills the service line and then nothing for an hour the partial blockage may be allowing enough water to pass.

Comment: Also if the problem is a partial blockage it could be that the partial blockage becomes a full blockage which eventually dislodges back to a partial blockage from the column of water pressing against it.